# .Net Runtime Error Stopping Service; Unhandled IOException

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have been put in charge of updating a service that reads a text file and creates pdf files from sections of the text file and emails out the pdfs. I recently made some changes to the service and used the .Net 4.0 Framework. When updating on the server, the 4.0 Framework was installed before I could move my files and start the service successfully - it was using 2.0 previously. The service runs until it reaches code that attempts to clean up the directory with the pdf files. The service Stops when the code attempts to delete a pdf file which is "in use by another process". The code looks for this exception and is supposed to wait for about 30 seconds and try the delete again. Locally, I run this service through a test Harness and it loops through until the file becomes available to delete (on average it takes about 5 minutes), but on the server the Service stops with the Unhandled IOException found in the Application Event log. I don't understand why it will continue processing locally but not on the server. Any ideas or other information would greatly be appreciated.

Here is the error in the Event Log:

The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.

> Exception Info: System.IO.IOException
>   Stack:
>      at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
>      at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean, Boolean ByRef)
>      at processorName.FileProcessingThread.CleanUpDirectory(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(System.Object)

Also this error appears in the event log as well:

> EventType clr20r3, P1 myServiceName.exe, P2 1.0.1.0, P3 4db6e85d, P4 mscorlib, P5 4.0.0.0, P6 4d53693b, P7 3dab, P8 23b, P9 system.io.ioexception, P10 NIL.

Here is the code that is supposed to handle the exception, wait and retry to delete the files.

```
while (!isDone)
{
    bool myRetVal = true;
    string myErrorMsg = String.Empty;
    string myFile = String.Empty;
    //give it time to finish processing
    Thread.Sleep(30 * 1000);
    //
    //delete Files in folder
    foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(myDirectory, "*.PDF"))
    {  //delete all the *.PDF files
        try
        {
            File.Delete(file);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            myErrorMsg = "...\r\n" + ex.Message;
            m_Log.Writeline("Unable to delete "+ file + ". MESSAGE:"+ myErrorMsg,3);
            myFile = file;
            myRetVal = false;
        }
    }
    //
    //now move the in-progress File to the processed directory
    if (myRetVal)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(myDirectory, "*.InProgress"))
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists(m_ConfigFile.ProcessedFolderName + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".done"))
                {
                    File.Delete(file);
                }
                else
                {
                    File.Move(file, m_ConfigFile.ProcessedFolderName + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + ".done");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("file already exists"))
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    myErrorMsg = "...\r\n" + ex.Message;
                    myFile = file;
                    myRetVal = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //
    //if empty, delete the SendMailFolder subfolder
    if (myRetVal)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Directory.GetFiles(myDirectory, "*.*").Length == 0) Directory.Delete(myDirectory);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            myErrorMsg = "...\r\n" + ex.Message;
            myFile = myDirectory;
            myRetVal = false;
        }
    }

    if (Console.CursorLeft > 0) Console.WriteLine("\r\n");

    if (myRetVal)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + " CleanUp SendMailFolder...Done");
        isDone = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (myErrorMsg.Contains("is being used by another process."))
        {
            myErrorMsg = " is still in use.";
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + " CleanUp SendMailFolder..." + Path.GetFileName(myFile) + myErrorMsg);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + " CleanUp SendMailFolder..." + Path.GetFileName(myFile) + myErrorMsg);
            m_Log.Writeline(DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime() + " CleanUp SendMailFolder..." + Path.GetFileName(myFile) + myErrorMsg, 3);
            isDone = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use the Console class in a service, which doesn't have a console window associated with it. You should use some alternate form of logging that doesn't assume there's a console window. log4net, as one example, allows you to configure multiple "appenders", such as a console, file, and event log appender, to use simultaneously (and which will simply be ignored if they aren't appropriate).

EDIT to clarify:

You can create a console window manually with the `AllocConsole` P/Invoke call if you absolutely need to.  By default, a service doesn't interact with your desktop, so creating a console window would be a bad idea. For that to work you would need to configure the service with the **"Allow service to interact with the desktop"** setting turned on. This has security implications, particularly for machines that have multiple users, so I would advise against it.

Comment: Is this causing the error? I don't understand why it was written with the console stuff either and I don't think its necessary as some of logging in the service writes to a log file already.

Comment: +1. Note the exception trace: `at System.Console.GetBufferInfo(Boolean, Boolean ByRef)` It is the use of the Console that is causing a problem, not interacting with the files. I would remove or change the calls to `Console.CursorLeft` and `Console.WriteLine`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there error is happening before your try catch. Given that you should see the specific message output by your logging (I assume it goes to the Event Log). I don't see a message that looks like what is in your log. You might want to have an app domain exception handler to catch any exceptions and log them.

Comment: The logging within the code is done to a file or to the console (which I can see when testing locally through my harness). The logs and directory contents points to the fact that pdf files are being deleted until the code reaches one that is still in use (and in use by what process, I have no idea) so there are files deleted from the directory and the main txt file is still there with the .InProgress extension which means its never getting moved to the Processed Directory . Shouldn't I get the exception when testing locally if its outside my try catch?

Comment: Not sure. If the directory doesn't exist on the server then something else could fail and throw the IOException. That is why I think you are seeing something outside your code.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should ensure your m_log routine has proper error handling as that could be the culprit as well.